# I'm trying to include <sys/lock.h> in my source on a redhat enterprise linux server, need to install it

Tags: include, locking, libraries, freebsd, rhel

I'm trying to include sys/lock.h in my source on a redhat enterprise linux server, but the file isn't installed on the system so I want to install it.  I'm pretty sure it's in freebsd and I need to know how to install freebsd.

This is a programming-specific devops-type question so if you can tell me elsewhere to post it I'll do that.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilites:

1. you are on a hardened system where the development packages are not installed, thus the header file does not show up
2. it might be the case that the header file is differently named in Linux compared to BSD.

Watch your compiler output what defines are missing and use grep to see, whether the missing defines are in different header files (find /usr/include -type f -print | xargs grep $1)

In the old days where I had to compile BSD and SYSV sources on other systems (SCO, Linux, etc) I wrote some easy shell scripts "isinc" and "islib" to check, in which header files defines for a certain "expression" and in which libraries functions are defined.